# Next.js custom _error page only works locally

Tags: next.js, netlify, vercel

Here's a link to my repo to demonstrate the problem: https://github.com/jonathanwelton/nextjs-custom-error-test

I'm trying to use a custom _error page in Next.js, which works on a local production build (npm run build && npm start) when you visit /throw (a page that throws an error), but neither Netlify or Vercel respect it when the app is deployed. I just receive a stack trace, which you can see here: https://nextjs-custom-error-test.netlify.app/throw

Reverting to Next.js 9.4.4, the custom _error page works on Vercel, but it doesn't appear you can deploy a Next.js app below version 10 on Netlify.

I just updated the app to use Next v11.0.0, but the problem still remains.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to add a `pages/500.js`?
On Vercel and locally, it works flawlessly: https://nextjs-custom-error-test-rho.vercel.app/throw
Perhaps Netlify does not support this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-error-page

We need to pass props and determine whether to show actual page or error page.

Modify code like this

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
  try {
     // Your statements
     throw new Error('a new error')

     return {
      props: { data: [] },
     }
  } catch(e) {
     return {
         props: { errorCode: 500 },
     }
  }
}

const Throw = ({ errorCode, ...data }) {
  if (errorCode) {
    return <Error statusCode={errorCode} />
  }

  return <div>{...}</div>
}
export default Throw;
```

Comment: hey @p2pdops, I updated the throw page to match your changes above, but it still has the same issue: https://nextjs-custom-error-test.netlify.app/throw

It's worth reiterating that the old code did work with Next.js 9.4.4

Comment: Hi @JonathanWelton, it says visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=31&args[]=Error%3A%20%5Bobject%20Object%5D so React is trying to render an object.. it means _error.js is sent but there is some object being passed do checkout